# Constraint Outlet position

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue with an imageOutlet on a view controller (First picture), it seems that it's  constraints issue. I thought I have not set up properly the constraint on the `GoalsVC`, but  after multiple verifications I noticed I am using the same constraints as the second picture (`assistVC`) scene.

I even deleted the goalsVC scene and copied the `assistVC` scene in order to make sure I have the same constraints and just hooked up the Goal swift file and each outlets again. Thought it maybe an issue with the View content Mode, but nope.

However the result is still different between them.   Any ideas or suggestions.

[image: Picture One]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check both images ratio means, Are they Aspect fit or Aspect fill @vangola

Comment: Both are on Aspect fit.

Comment: Using the Debug View hierarchy, I see that the content mode change to scale to fill, while it's set Aspect Fit. what could the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fixed it by resizing the image:

```
extension UIImage {
   func resize(_ width: CGFloat, _ height:CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
         let widthRatio  = width / size.width
         let heightRatio = height / size.height
         let ratio = widthRatio > heightRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio
         let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
         let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
         self.draw(in: rect)
         let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
         return newImage
     }
}
```